# Why does multiprocessing Julia break my module imports?

Tags: module, multiprocessing, julia

My team is trying to run a library (Cbc with JuMP) with multiprocessing and using the `julia -p #` argument. Our code is in a julia package and so we can run our code fine using `julia --project`, it just runs with one process. Trying to specify both at once however `julia --project -p 8` breaks our ability to run the project since running `using PackageName` after results in an error. We also intend to compile this using the `PackageCompiler` library so getting it to work with a project is necessary.

We have our project in a folder with a src directory, a Project.toml, and a Manifest.toml
src contains: main.jl and Solver.jl

Project.toml contains:

```
name = "Solver"
uuid = "5a323fe4-ce2a-47f6-9022-780aeeac18fe"
authors = ["..."]
version = "0.1.0"
```

Normally, our project works fine starting this way (single threaded):

```
julia --project
julia> using Solver
julia> include("src/main.jl")
```

If we add the `-p 8` argument when starting Julia, we get an error upon typing `using Solver`:

```
ERROR: On worker 2:
ArgumentError: Package Solver [5a323fe4-ce2a-47f6-9022-780aeeac18fe] is required but does not seem to be installed:
 - Run `Pkg.instantiate()` to install all recorded dependencies.
```

We have tried running `using Pkg; Pkg.instantiate(); using Solver` but this doesn't help as another error just happens later (at the `include("src/main.jl")` step):

```
ERROR: LoadError: On worker 2:
ArgumentError: Package Solver not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("Solver")` to install the Solver package.
```

and then following that suggestion produces another error:

```
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * Solver (not found in project, manifest or registry)
Please specify by known `name=uuid`.
```

Why does this module import work **fine in single process mode**, but **not with `-p 8`**?

Thanks in advance for your consideration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue with Julia when an uncompiled module exists and several parallel processes try to compile it at the same time for the first use.

Hence, if you are running your own module across many processes on a single machine you always need to run in the following way (this assumes that Julia process is run in the same folder where your project is located):

```
using Distributed, Pkg
@everywhere using Distributed, Pkg
Pkg.activate(".")
@everywhere Pkg.activate(".")
using YourModuleName
@everywhere using YourModuleName
```

I think this approach is undocumented but I found it experimentally to be most robust. 
If you do not use my pattern sometimes (not always!) a compiler chase occurs and strange things tend to happen.

Note that if you are running a distributed cluster you need to modify the code above to run the initialization on a single worker from each node and than on all workers.

Comment: I have the exact same problem as @joshua-stowell, but your solution doesn't seem to help in my case. I have tried `everywhere Pkg.activate(".")`, even `@everywhere Pkg.instantiate()`, but I still get the same error message when I first try to use my module. Do you perhaps have any other hints what I can look for to solve this? Could it be that the error is because this particular module was added with a git repo URL?

Also note, that in this particular case, I'm using Julia 1.0.5, because our production code is still running on that version. Could this be the reason of the error message?

Comment: You should always do Pkg.activate(".");@everywhere Pkg.activate(".") - not just `@everywhere` because than you have an activation chase. You NEVER should do anything like `@everywhere Pkg.instantiate()` because this will cause the package manager to simultaneously install the same set packages on the same machine by several parallel processes and you cannot expect package installation scripts to be designed for such occasion. If you have done this your package repository is likely to be broken - try deleting `.julia` folder and reinstalling all packages. Julia 1.0.5 should not matter here.

Answer (score 6):

First it is important to note that you are NOT using multi-thread parallelism, you are using distributed parallelism. When you initiate with `-p 2` you are launching two different processes that do not share the same memory. Additionally, the project is only being loaded in the master process, that is why the other processes cannot see whatever is in the project. You can learn more about the different kinds of parallelism that Julia offers [in the official documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/parallel-computing/).

To load the environment in all the workers, you can add this to the beginning of your file.

```
using Distributed
addprocs(2; exeflags="--project")
@everywhere using Solver
@everywhere include("src/main.jl")
```

and remove the `-p 2` part of the line which you launch julia with. This will load the project on all the processes.  The `@everywhere` macro is used to indicate all the process to perform the given task. [This part of the docs explains it.](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/parallel-computing/#Starting-and-managing-worker-processes-1)

Be aware, however, that parallelism doesn't work automatically, so if your software is not written with distributed parallelism in mind, it may not get any benefit from the newly launched workers.

Comment: I have never really used processes, but is `@everywhere using Solver` also an option?

Comment: It is needed, but it will work only after all the workers load the project environment.

Comment: Thanks for the input ARamirez. I tried your suggestion but still meet a similar error upon running ```@everywhere using Solver```: ERROR: ArgumentError: Package Solver not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("Solver")` to install the Solver package.

Comment: Did you add the exeflags to addprocs? Did you get any error there?

Comment: Putting the configuration issues aside, this will sometimes work and sometimes will not - see my answer below.

Comment: @ARamirez Yes, I added the exeflags. No error there, only when doing ```@everywhere using Solver```